# Create Grid Layout with 5 columns

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to understand basics of android layouts. So, because of it, I had decided to create calculator app with 2 views: basic and scientific.

So, I finished creating a basic layout, and now trying to create scientific layout with one more row with operations like pow, sqrt, ln and etc.

And I faced trouble while to add new column to existing layout: when I trying to add new button, it goes beyond the screen.

So, the queston is: how to make grid layout with 5 columns without hardcoding button's width?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context="android.calcandroid.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="0"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:background="#e3e7ea"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp"
            android:padding="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80">

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            grid:useDefaultMargins="false"
            grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            grid:columnCount="7"
            grid:rowCount="9">

            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <Button
                android:text="C"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/calcAccent"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="&#247;"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                grid:layout_column="4"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="x"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcAction"/>

            <!-- Row 2 -->
            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="1"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="7"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="8"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="9"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="-"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <!-- Row 3 -->

            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="3"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="4"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="5"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="6"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="+"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="7"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>

            <!-- Row 4 -->

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="1"
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="2"
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="3"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>

            <Button
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                grid:layout_rowSpan="3"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="@color/calcAccent"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="="
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>
            <!-- Row 5 -->

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                grid:layout_row="8"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="3"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                android:text="0"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_row="8"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                android:text="."/>

            <!-- Horizontal Grid -->
            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="5" grid:layout_column="0" grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And how it looks with 4 columns: [4 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uMK1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as noone answered, I had solved this by myself.

The issue was in hardcoding button's grid cells number and also in my not full understanding of grid:layout_columnWeight & grid:layout_rowWeight.

So I removed hardcoded values and here is the full code of solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context="android.calcandroid.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="0"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:background="#e3e7ea"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp"
            android:padding="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80">

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            grid:useDefaultMargins="false"
            grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            grid:columnCount="5"
            grid:rowCount="5">

            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="ln"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcAction"/>

            <Button
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="C"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/calcAccent"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="&#247;"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="x"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcAction"/>

            <!--  Row 2 -->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="log"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="7"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="8"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="9"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="-"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <!-- Row 3 -->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="\u221A"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="5"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="6"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="+"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <!-- Row 4 -->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="^"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="3"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                grid:layout_rowSpan="2"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="@color/calcAccent"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="="
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>

            <!-- Row 5 -->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="!"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                android:text="0"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                android:text="."/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And a screenshot: [pretty nice!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNCjV.png)

Hope that this answer will help somebody.